# Java Concurrency on JDBC result

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate, java.util.concurrent

I would like to apply Java Concurrent i.e. Callable for resultset. The scenario is -

1. Query the DB using JDBC.
2. Send the resultset to callable to write to different files.

Since the data would be large i would like to resultset. Please help me to get better approach for the problem.

Comment: I do not understand what you problem is. You can return resultsets through Future, don't you? Adam gave me the light-up. And I agree with him.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way ResultSet is designed it is not supposed to be used concurrently by many threads. But you can create one thread that iterates over the result set and send row data to Callables that will perform further processing of each row (or group of rows).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are programming under swing or javaFX, then you are blocking the GUI thread.

So you must create another Thread to process the jdbc request, and display a 'please wait' message.

Do something like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
  void run(){
   final result = jdbc.getResultSet();
   // Under JavaFX 2
   Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
                 //Show results
          }
   } );
   // Under Swing
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
                 //Show results
          }
   });
  }
}
);
```